# C# multiple connect to Selenium grid or speed up parallel testing in Selenium grid

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

I have some question about the remoteweb driver in Parallel testing.

Because i have to Parallel to speed up the Selenium grid to open the page,

1.When i use the code that like this . It will Parallel to connect the Grid,but

every time  it will reopen the webdriver again.It will cause some delay. **How could i using Parallel to connect  Selenium grid but no need to restart webedriver.**

**2.How could i check RemoteWebDriver resource is free so that my thread could 
continue using it.**

```
Parallel.ForEach(PartThreading, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (keyValue) =>
{

    var _driver = new RemoteWebDriver(_options.RemoteHubUrl, DesiredCapabilities.Chrome()); // instead of this url you can put the url of your remote hub

    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(keyValue.Key);

    SaveHtmlAndScreenShot(keyValue.Key, _driver);

    GetUnvisitedLinks(_driver, keyValue.Key);
    _driver.Quit();

});
```

Thanks